# Accessing UIView from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have added a UIView to a UIViewController using storyboards (See Image Below)

The problem is I cannot access anything from the UIView. I believe the issue is because when I init the class which UIView uses, I am creating a new instance of VASettingsView rather than using the one which has been added to the UIView frame using storyboards:

[image: White Background is a view controller (VARendererViewController), Blue Background is a UIView (VASettingsView)]

VARendererViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
...
    // Initalise settings subview
    self.settingsInit = [[VASettingsView alloc] init];
    self.settingsInit.delegate = self;
....
}

-(void)update{
        int test = [[self settingsInit] getTest];
        NSLog(@"%d", test);
}
```

Returns 0, Should return '12345'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only use the [tag:Xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you should not need to create a new `VASettingsView` in `-viewDidLoad`.  Is `settingsInit` declared as an `IBOutlet`?  You should be able to make a connection from the `VASettingsView` in Interface Builder to the outlet in your view controller.

`-viewDidLoad` is the method that is called after your nib is loaded; at that point all of the `IBOutlets` that were connected in your nib will be available for you to use.  It is not necessary to create and set those properties.

Comment: I have linked the UIView referencing outlet to an IBOutlet in VARendererViewController of type UIView. What else am I required to link up?

Comment: You need a link from the `VARendererViewController`'s settingsInit outlet to the VASettingsView object in your nib.  This might be simpler if you show us a screenshot of your VARendererViewController connections in IB.

Comment: All fixed. Thank you very much